# Are older versions of MS SQL Server DEVELOPER edition now free?

Tags: sql-server, license

Microsoft SQL Server Developer Edition is now free  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/03/31/microsoft-sql-server-developer-edition-is-now-free/

I see that I can download 2016 and 2014, but are there downgrade rights to use 2012 and earlier versions?

Comment: I would say no - since its free for newer versions sql 2014 and up, but better to ask your Microsoft account manager. Just curious why would you downgrade to 2012 ?

Comment: @Kin Possibly as production is 2012 and they want the same version as production.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a licensing/legal question

Answer (score 0):

No, free is not backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2014 onwards, Microsft started to provide Developer edition for free. not for older versions.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/03/31/microsoft-sql-server-developer-edition-is-now-free/

Thanks!